# Get the value of static properties from static methods in JavascriptMVC

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller, javascriptmvc

I'm working on my first project with [JavascriptMVC](http://javascriptmvc.com/).

I have a class Foo.

```
$.Class('Foo',{
    // Static properties and methods
    message: 'Hello World',
    getMessage: function() {
        return Foo.message;
    }
},{});
```

This works fine. But what if I don't know the class name?
I want something like this:

```
$.Class('Foo',{
    // Static properties and methods
    message: 'Hello World',
    getMessage: function() {
        return this.message;
    }
},{});
```

but I can't use *this* in a static property. 
So, how can I get the current class name from a static method.

From a prototype method it is easy:

```
this.constructor.shortName/fullName.
```

but how to do it in a static method?

Comment: But you do know the class name... **?!**

Comment: In this situation I know it, but I want to write a parent class, with some static methods, and use this static methods in inherited classes. So the class name will change, for every inherited method. I don't want to define these static methods in every inherited class.

Answer (score 0):

The truth is, that I was wrong. It is possible to use *this* in a static method.
Here is a little code snippet that can help to understand how JavascriptMVC's static and prototype methods and properties work, also the scope of *this* in both of them.

```
$.Class('Foo', 
{
  aStaticValue: 'a static value',
  aStaticFunction: function() {
    return this.aStaticValue;
  }
}, 
{
  aPrototypeValue: 'a prototype value',
  aPrototypeFunction: function() {
    alert(this.aPrototypeValue); // alerts 'a prototype value'
    alert(this.aStaticValue); // alerts 'undefined'
    alert(this.constructor.aStaticValue); // alerts 'a static value'
  }
});

alert(Foo.aStaticFunction()); // alerts 'a static value'
var f = new Foo();
alert(f.aPrototypeValue); // alerts 'a prototype value'
f.aPrototypeFunction();
```